# CSV exporting number with leading zeros readable in excel

Tags: ruby, fastercsv

Is it possible to influence ruby CSV module to add equal sign before quoted field, so generated csv is readable in excel and does not loose leading zero.

Current result is:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > CSV.generate_line(["01"], :force_quotes => true)
 => "\"01\"\n"
```

Preferred would be:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > CSV.generate_line(["01"], :force_quotes => true)
 => "=\"01\"\n"
```

I know there is option to import text file in excel, but I would like to avoid this and be able just to double click on the file to open it.

Answer (score 0):

CSV is for generating CSV, not Excel files. So you either need to monkey-patch CSV yourself, but probably for your purposes `Spreadsheet::Excel` is a better option. This allows you to generate native Excel files, where you should pretty much be able to set the column formatting options directly to match what you are looking for:

http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/file.GUIDE.html

Comment: Thanks for answer. I would like to generate CSV files but unfortunately it parse anything that looks like a number as a number, no matter if it does have leading zeros or spaces in it. There is a workaround around that described here http://creativyst.com/Doc/Articles/CSV/CSV01.htm#CSVAndExcel. I am hoping it could be achieved with CSV from standard library.

Comment: Sure..but by generating a non-standard CSV file you might as well create an Excel file instead. However..you could also do `generate_line(["=\"01\""], ...)`...or something similar (with the correct quoting). That could work also.

Comment: unfortunately ``generate_line(["=\"01\""], ...)`` would not work as equal sign should be outside. I hoped that CSV could be easily extended to handle this.